# Continue line under number in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

Is it possible to extend the line so it goes under the number?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
 \vspace{0.3cm}
      \hrule
      \vspace{0.1cm}
      
\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=2cm,align=left,label={\arabic*}]
    \item \lipsum[1]
     \vspace{0.3cm}
      \hrule
      \vspace{0.1cm}
    \item \lipsum[1]
      \vspace{0.3cm}
      \hrule
      \vspace{0.1cm}
    \item text
     \vspace{0.3cm}
      \hrule
      \vspace{0.1cm}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[labelsep=0cm,align=left,label={\arabic*}]
        \item \hrule
        \vspace{0.1cm}
        \lipsum[1]
        \vspace{0.3cm}

        \item \hrule
        \vspace{0.1cm}
        \lipsum[1]
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        

        \item \hrule
        \vspace{0.1cm}
        text
        \vspace{0.3cm}
        \hrule
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow! Perfect, thank you 

Comment: @WendyTaylor No upvote?

Comment: Sorry, definitely deserves an upvote!

Comment: Is there a way to increase the space between the numbers and the text by about 1cm?